# Android resources size qualifiers can't be determined by some devices

Tags: android, android-resources

By design I have two pictures: for devices whose screen height is less than 600dp and other devices. I created two xml files for this pictures in `drawable-h600dp` and `drawable` folders.

Content of `drawable-h600dp/logo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/logo_big" />
```

Content of `drawable/logo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/logo_small" />
```

This solution works on most devices. But some devices e.g. LG Nexus5 (640dp height) and Motorola RAZR HD (640dp height) show small picture instead of big. *I get device screen height in dp from 'ScreenInfo' google play application.*

There is **only portrait** configuration, landscape is disabled.

Is there any way to determinate screen height correctly for resources?